# Does each MatrixBlockModel in an entry have a unique dateUpdated?

Tags: matrix, datetime

After doing some experimentation in looping through `MatrixBlockModel`, it seems that even though each block has a `dateUpdated` property, this value is never unique to each block, but is shared between all blocks in the Entry.

```
{% set timeLimit = now | date_modify("-2 min") %}
{% for block in entry.blocks %}
  {% if block.dateUpdated >= timeLimit %}

    {{ block.dateUpdated | date(dtFilter) }}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the entry has 6 blocks, and I update one of those blocks and save, the same date will output 6 times for about 2 minutes, then nothing will output.

Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I can confirm, currently the `dateUpdated` property returns the same datetime object for every block model. It's actually the save date of the entry (`entry.dateUpdated`) that is saved to the `craft_matrixblocks` table in the DB.

Can't say if it's intended to work like this though.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @carlcs. If this _is_ the intended behavior, its a bit of a bummer because I have a use case (checking for recently-updated matrix blocks via a javascript JSON request) that is far more difficult, maybe even impossible, without a unique updated date time for each block. It's also inconsistent, because each block **does** have a unique `date_created` property.

Comment: @cmal the (shared) property is probably only saved to make this work: `block.dateUpdated`. But actually that wouldn't be necessary because you could also do: `block.owner.dateUpdated`.

Comment: I did a [feature request](https://plus.google.com/101325980081569498457/posts/YUcDZu9sdkz) for this on g+.